# how to know the rotation direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm making game where the player can rotate flat object to any direction or flip it or anything

also i want to have four texts on the four sides to show the amount of rotation on each side ( see the pictures for better idea )

[image: idea about the game]

and here is the code am using to rotate it and show the rotation

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class main_code : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text show_right_rotation;
public Text show_left_rotation;
public Text show_up_rotation;
public Text show_down_rotation;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    if ((int)transform.eulerAngles.z >= 180 && (int)transform.eulerAngles.z <= 360)
    {
        show_right_rotation.text = (360 - ((int)transform.eulerAngles.z)).ToString();
    }
    else if ((int)transform.eulerAngles.z <= 180 && (int)transform.eulerAngles.z >= 0)
    {
        show_left_rotation.text = ((int)transform.eulerAngles.z).ToString();
    }

    if ((int)transform.eulerAngles.x >= 0 && (int)transform.eulerAngles.x <= 90)
    {
        show_up_rotation.text = ((int)transform.eulerAngles.x).ToString();
    }
    else if ((int)transform.eulerAngles.x <= 360 && (int)transform.eulerAngles.x >= 270)
    {
        show_down_rotation.text = (360 - ((int)transform.eulerAngles.x)).ToString();
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), Space.World);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Space.World);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -1), Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), Space.World);
    }
}
}
```

now if i click right arrow while the y axis is 0 the flat will rotate correctly and i can use transform.eulerAngles values to know the rotation to which direction and the rotation value as you can see it show that the flat is rotated 72 degree to the right

[image: the correct result]

the problem is if the flat y axis is not 0 any more then the transform.eulerAngles values will became useless as you can see in the image it show it rotated 44 to right and 33 to up while its not rotated to up

[image: the wrong result]

so how can i show the amount of rotation to each side regardless of y axis value ?

Comment: what values other than what `localEulerAngles` gives you would you expect to get?

Comment: you could try reparenting the object so that you can use localEuler.x instead of .z for example. order materrs in rotations